# How to use elfinder in node.js (express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, elfinder

My project requires me to make a file manager and I just saw elfinder and it looks great but it's in php and my project is in node(express). Is there a way to use elfinder in node?

I saw https://github.com/sax1johno/node-elfinder but it doesn't have any documentation on how to use implement it. And is there also a way to use Amazon s3 instead of the local folder?